# Grails hasOne vs. belongsTo

Tags: grails, grails-orm

To create one-to-one relationships in Grails I can do:

```
class Person {
    static hasOne = [address: Address]
}
```

In this case the Address table has the key to its person. I could also do:

```
class Address {
    static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
```

This gives the same result.

**What is the difference between my two samples using `hasOne` and `belongsTo`?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`hasOne` indicates that there is a bi-directional one-to-one relationship where the child table has the parent's foreign key, as in your example.

`belongsTo` is used to control cascades by indicating that the class belongs to the specified class. In your example, deleting a given `Person` would cascade the delete to any associated `Address`es.

Comment: In the example in this question, how do I get the child Id to be in the parent field so that I can do something like: `user.address` to get the address of a given user?

Comment: @Pila, the current mapping in the question does what you are saying: you can write `user.address` to access the user's address.